# Merge two datasets with similar index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've tried combining two data frames from different sources. I've tried most methods to merge/join/concat but not having any look combining them. here is an example:

````
              Population  ...  CSSSA LEGAL?
Afghanistan          NaN  ...            NO
Afghanistan   31056997.0  ...           NaN
Albania              NaN  ...           YES
Albania        3581655.0  ...           NaN
Algeria              NaN  ...            NO
...                  ...  ...           ...
Yemen         21456188.0  ...           NaN
Zambia               NaN  ...            NO
Zambia        11502010.0  ...           NaN
Zimbabwe             NaN  ...            NO
Zimbabwe      12236805.0  ...           NaN


```
import pandas as pd


data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0)
key_data = data[['Population', 'Literacy (%)', 'GDP ($ per capita)',
                 'Phones (per 1000)', 'Infant mortality (per 1000 births)']]
key_data = key_data.replace(',', '.', regex=True)
key_data['Literacy (%)'] = pd.to_numeric(key_data['Literacy (%)'], downcast="float")
key_data['Phones (per 1000)'] = pd.to_numeric(key_data['Phones (per 1000)'], downcast="float")
key_data['Infant mortality (per 1000 births)'] = pd.to_numeric(key_data['Infant mortality (per 1000 births)'], downcast="float")
df1 = key_data

lgbt_data = pd.read_excel('lgbt_data.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', header=1)
key_lgbt_data = lgbt_data[['COUNTRY', 'CSSSA LEGAL?']]
key_lgbt_data = key_lgbt_data.set_index('COUNTRY')
df2 = key_lgbt_data


df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how="outer")

print(df3)`
````

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer! The index of df1 contained a blank space after each entry so duplicate strings weren't recognised